# Update Multiple records in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my situation:

I use the SqlCommond to update some records in the SQL Server in a ASP.NET web site. Users can choose which records they want to update. Sometimes they may choose 40 or 60 records to update at a time.Is there any good way to do it? I do not want to do like it

```
foreach(string ID in List)
{
   Update here
}
```

Best Regards,

Comment: Just curious, what is wrong with doing it in the foreach()?

Answer (score 3):

You can send one SQL string ith all the update statements together. Nothing says a SQL "round trip" can not execute multiple statements or even multiple batches.

Comment: That is correct, but that doesn't change anything. Besides - SqlCommand will not execute GO commands. This is only possible in SMO.

Answer (score 1):

yes we can do thing in one round tip. create xml string of the selected id and pass to the procedure as and Varchar(max) argument.

and in sql part use `openXml` and update data.

check th post : 
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/OpenXML/usingopenxml/1881/